# Order of images in DropzoneJS Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone div that I have enabled sorting on, like this:

```
<div>
    <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="image-dropzone">
        <div class="fallback"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#image-dropzone").sortable({
            items:'.dz-preview',
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.5,
            containment: '#image-dropzone',
            distance: 20,
            tolerance: 'pointer'
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I determine the order of the images in this dropzone?  I would like to be able to change another part of my page every time the images' order is altered, and then be able to upload the images in the order they are left in.

Comment: you are missing a closing }); in your script

Comment: Hah, thanks.  I had just copied and pasted out of a larger subset of JS.  It's fixed now.